# \n is messing my script up

Tags: python, cisco

I have a script that will successfully run if I assign a list inside the main function, but I need to run through this on 100+ devices. I've spent some time researching and I think the best way to do this would be to store the variables in a text file and access it that way. (Of course, if someone knows a better way, I'm all for it!)

My issue now is that when I try to convert the existing code to account for the new text file full of variables, I'm getting:

`TypeError: getaddrinfo() argument 1 must be string or None"`

I'm pretty sure I'm seeing those because of the `\n` line break because it will fail up until the last line, and that one works.

So far, I've tried the `line.split` & save the txt file as a .csv and change the delimiter to `\n` but neither are working quite the way I expected.

Below is the script that works:

```
import sys, os, string, threading
import getpass
import paramiko
import time


cmd = "sh vl bri"
lanid = 'admin'
pwd = 'password'


outlock = threading.Lock()

def workon(host):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(host, username=lanid, password=pwd)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    #print stdout.read()
    stdin.flush()

    with open("output-" + host + ".txt", 'w+') as f:
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(stdout.read())

    with outlock:
        print stdout.readlines()
        #f.write(stdout)


def main():
    hosts = ['sw1', 'sw2', 'sw3'] # etc
    threads = []
    for h in hosts:
        t = threading.Thread(target=workon, args=(h,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


main()
```

**EDIT 1**

```
import sys, os, string, threading
import getpass
import paramiko
import time


cmd = "sh vl bri"
#lanid = raw_input("Enter your uname: ")
lanid = 'admin'
pwd = 'password'


outlock = threading.Lock()

def workon(stripped_row):
    ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())
    ssh.connect(stripped_row, username=lanid, password=pwd)
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(cmd)
    #print stdout.read()
    stdin.flush()

    with open("output-" + stripped_row + ".txt", 'w+') as f:
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(stdout.read())

    with outlock:
        print stdout.readlines()
        #f.write(stdout)



def main():
    my_file = open('10host.txt')
    threads = []
    for h in my_file:
        striped_row = h.strip()
        t = threading.Thread(target=workon, args=(h,))
        t.start()
        threads.append(t)
    for t in threads:
        t.join()


main()
```

Comment: Could you just call `.strip()` on each line? Or `.replace("\n", "")`?

Comment: I've tried both and i still get the same error. Maybe I'm placing it incorrectly. Where exactly in the code above would I need to do the replace or strip? I was assuming inside the for loop directly after the for statement....

Comment: I would expect an addition of, for example, `my_file = open("path_to_file"); for row in my_file: stripped_row = row.strip() #Do something with stripped_row` I guess I'm not 100% sure on what you're wanting - would the file be replacing `hosts` in `main()`?

Comment: The code that doesn't work and the full stacktrace would both likely help too.

Comment: Anyway, if what I supposed is indeed what you're looking for, I would replace the `hosts` declaration line with the something along the lines of the code I put in that comment.

Comment: You have code that works, and code that doesn't work.... and you want us to fix the code that doesn't work by showing us the code that does work. That is not how this game is played!

Comment: Moreover, what we need is **the smallest possible amount of code, built to be independently runnable/testable, necessary to demonstrate what doesn't work**. More code to dig through before getting to the core of the problem helps nobody. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Also, there's no need for "EDIT 1", "EDIT 2", etc -- everyone can see edit history as diffs. Try to make your final, edited post as readable as possible for someone looking at it for the first time; don't worry about calling out what was or wasn't edited -- the diff history is very good at showing that for those who need it.

Answer (score 0):

The problem lies here:

```
for h in my_file:
    striped_row = h.strip()
    t = threading.Thread(target=workon, args=(h,))
```

You're stripping the current line, but then pass the unstripped line to your worker function. Try to pass the `striped_row` as argument instead of `h`.